# UITextField - shouldChangeCharactersIn with self.addSubview()

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, uitextfield

My problem is that if I do my customization UITextField, then shouldChangeCharactersIn() method is not called, but if I do not apply to this customization, everything goes fine.

I use the library SkyFloatingLabelTextField

First file:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailField.setRegistrationFieldStyleWith(title: "E-mail")
    emailField.delegate = self
}
```

Second file with Extensions:

```
func setRegistrationFieldStyleWith(title: String) {
    let textField = SkyFloatingLabelTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 215, height: 40))
    textField.placeholder = title
    textField.title = title

    textField.tintColor = overcastBlueColor 
    ...
    ...

    self.addSubview(textField)
}
```

Maybe who faced with this library? Or input processing method starts to behave differently, if the fields to customize?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Try textField.delegate = self in setRegistrationFieldStyleWith method

Comment: I want to add a simple check on the validity of an email. When changing UITextField call the shouldChangeCharactersIn method. 
Usually it worked, but when I use the library it stopped working, so I think, answer on the surface or worth exploring the library?! :)

Comment: textField is added as the subView of  emailField. But you were set the delegate to emailField. I think that is the problem. The delegate should be set to textField which added as the subview of emailField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    emailField.setRegistrationFieldStyleWith(title: "E-mail")

    for view in emailField.subviews {

        if view.isKind(of: UITextField.self) {

            let textFieldView = view as! UITextField
            textFieldView.delegate = self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still not understand how it works, but it really works: D
Thank!

Comment: Welcome bro :-)

Comment: Here i am just finding that customized textField which is added as a  subview of emailField and setting delegate to that. When you are typing in emailField, you are actually typing in the customized textField  because it is a subview of emailField. So in order to work the delegate method for customize textField, you should set the delegate to that textField, not to emailField. Hope you understand